# How can I combine two 16-bit values into a single 32-bit value when either one is negative?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have found several threads on Stack Overflow demonstrating how to combine two 16-bit values into a 32-bit value when both operands are positive numbers but I have come to discover these do not work if either operand is negative.

Here is what I am currently working with:

```
uint32_t combined(uint16_t low, uint16_t high)
{
  return (static_cast<uint32_t>(high) << 16) + static_cast<uint32_t>(low);
}
```

This returns the correct value only when `high` and `low` are positive. How can I modify this function to return the correct result when one or both arguments are negative?

Comment: Unsigned cannot be negative, so not sure what you mean by "correct result"

Comment: This is because the [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is used to represent negative numbers.

Comment: Use `|` instead of `+`. Then the higher 16 bit are exactly the bits of `high` and the lower those of `low`. You can get those back by shifting left by 16 for `high` and by left and right shifting for `low`. Note that, arithmetically the resulting number has not a direct correspondence to the input. It works for storing those two in 32 bit. If you want a special combination of those two you have to do something different depending on the result you want.

Comment: @n314159 in this context replacing `+` with `|` will not change anything at all

Comment: Ah, yes sry, you have to get rid of the 1s that potentially are in front of the casted `low`. Not sure if shifting or and'ing is the easier solution. But conceptually, this should work, since the last 16 bit of the `int32_t` are the bits of the input `int16_t`, or am I mistaken?

Comment: What do you expect from `combined(-1, -42)` then?

Comment: Please provide examples of input number pairs and desired "correct" result. Start with the one by Jarod42. Provide examples of positive/positive, positive/negative, negative/positive, negative/negative. Combine with low values and high values (i.e. close to 16bit maximum value and close to 0); for a total of 16 different pairs. Making those examples might help you find the solution yourself.

Comment: Depends what you want it to do........

Comment: I do not understand question for me this code woks as expected: https://wandbox.org/permlink/QwU03dSdndhgciyM

Comment: Could it be that your original function parameters are *signed* 16-bit integers? If so, then just cast them to *unsigned* 16-bit integers *before* casting them to unsigned 32-bit ones to get around sign extension.

Comment: @Aconcagua Good guess, that was the issue all along.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you need:

```
uint32_t combined(uint16_t low, uint16_t high) {
    return (static_cast<uint32_t>(high) << 16) | ((static_cast<uint32_t>(low)) & 0xFFFF);
}
```

As I understand, leading 1s after converting negative number to `int` make a problem. They can are removed by `... & 0xFFFF`.

`&` is bitwice `and` operation. `0xFFFF` is the same as `0x0000FFFF` but shorter and `a & 0xFFFF` means "make first (high) 16 bit of `a` 0s and leave the rest as it is".

Comment: what is the purpose of `& 0xFFFF` when you used unsigned types?

Comment: Ok look like OP question is confusing, since his code just works as expected: https://wandbox.org/permlink/QwU03dSdndhgciyM

Comment: @MarekR i think `0xFFFF` mask is used to select lower 16 bits only and to discard remaining bits, however OP's question is absurd as this point.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the logic in the OP was fine but the data types I chose to use were incorrect based on my inputs (I realized this after slava's first reply). Below is the updated function:

```
int32_t combined(int16_t low, int16_t high)
{
  return (static_cast<uint32_t>(high) << 16) + static_cast<uint32_t>(low);
}
```

This now works as expected.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled about your expectations... `combined(-1, -1)` results in `0xfffeffff`. My expectations would have been `0xffffffff` instead. Or similarly, `combined(-1, 1)` gives `0x0000ffff`, while I'd have expected `0x0001ffff`

Comment: Well, you still get a bijection that way. Actually, you add -1 to high, if low is negative. Hopefully, you have considered this when calculating back the two original values...